# Template file is not recognized

Tags: 8, theming

I enabled theme debugging in services.yml file and I added a template file.
Following is what I see in file name suggestions:

`x layout--onecol.html.twig
* layout-onecol--taxonomy-term--1.html.twig
* layout-onecol--taxonomy-term-branches-default.html.twig
* layout-onecol--taxonomy-term-branches.html.twig
* layout-onecol--taxonomy-term-default.html.twig
* layout-onecol--taxonomy-term.html.twig
x layout--onecol.html.twig
* layout.html.twig`

Here's new file's name:

`layout-onecol--taxonomy-term-branches-default.html.twig`

The file is not recognized. The page is still rendering from

`<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/layout/layout--onecol.html.twig' -->`

So, I tried adding **layout--onecol.html.twig** file in my custom theme.
And this file is recognized which means file names with * in suggestions list are not working, but names with x are recognized.

I believe they should work in opposite way.

Comment: Is it `layout-onecol` or `layout--onecol`? Notice the count of hyphens. Clearly the code suggesting template names with taxonomy terms is different then the default. I'd check out that implementation. Also, wouldn't hurt trying to rename your template to `layout--onecol--taxonomy-term-branches-default.html.twig`.

Comment: @osman Thanks for reply. it is `layout--onecol.html.twig`. I've tried `layout--onecol--taxonomy-term-branches-default.html.twig`.

Comment: Did you clear the caches after adding your template?

Comment: The **x** represents the current theme file name being rendered * represents other available file name suggestions. I don't know why in your case `layout--onecol.html.twig` comes again at top

Comment: `layout--onecol--taxonomy-term-branches-default.html.twig` How you get this suggestion is it through `hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter` then check the variable passed to `$suggestions`